# Java ANT build.xml error driver not found

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, ant, postgresql-10

Hello i have a problem,

i'm in the first trying to get an ant command working succesfully but i have some problem.

When i digit on my cmd ant in the project folder the prject compile correctly and then when i have to connect to my postgres server it crash saying: 
DBManager,SignIn,No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/dbName

Here you can see my build.xml file (but i'm not sure the error is over there)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<project basedir="." default="execute" name="BuildReader">

<!-- Config File -->


<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->


<!-- DON'T TOUCH HERE -->


<property name="path" value="./"/>

<property name="name" value="reader"/>

<property name="source_dir" value="."/>


-<path id="build.classpath">

<fileset dir="./Lib" includes="*.jar"/>

</path>


-<target name="init">

<echo message="* Creating folder '${path}/export'"/>

<mkdir dir="${path}/export"/>

<mkdir dir="${path}/export/tmp"/>

</target>


-<target name="build" depends="init">

<echo message="* Starting Building '${name}'"/>


-<javac srcdir="${source_dir}" destdir="${path}/export/tmp" includeantruntime="false">

<classpath refid="build.classpath"/>

</javac>

</target>


-<target name="jar" depends="build">

<echo message="* Creating JAR packet of '${name}'"/>


-<jar basedir="${path}/export/tmp" destfile="${path}/export/${name}.jar">


-<manifest>

<attribute name="Main-Class" value="Server.ServeMainClass"/>

</manifest>

</jar>

<delete dir="${path}/export/tmp"/>

</target>


-<target name="execute" depends="jar">

<echo message="* Starting App '${name}'"/>

<java jar="${path}/export/${name}.jar" fork="true"/>

</target>

</project>
```

As i said the program is starting when i digit ant in the project folder but when i enter the server credential i get this error (the program isn't crashing but it wont neither log to the server)

Here u can see the conncetion to the server

```
private void setup() throws SQLException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while ((conn == null) || (conn.isClosed())) {

            System.out.println("Insert host");
            String host = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Insert Username");
            String user = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Insert Password");
            String psw = scan.nextLine();

            String connectionStringU = "jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":5432/dbSeatIn";

            // conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, userName, password);
            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionStringU, user, psw);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.WriteError(e, "sas", "sssss");
                try {
                    PulisciConsole();
                } catch (IOException e1) {

                }
                System.out.println("Connection failed");
                Logger.WriteError(e, "DBManager", "SignIn");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Connection up");

        System.out.println("Loading setUpList");

        CommonList.Updatesip(conn);
        CommonList.UpdateCourse(conn);
        CommonList.UpdateSubj(conn);

        System.out.println("List loaded");

    }
```

Can someone pls help me to find out where i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Add the **PostgreSQL** JDBC driver to ANT's `CLASSPATH`....

Comment: i just googled but i dont' know how to do it

Comment: What don't you know, exactly? How to find and download the PostgreSQL JDBC driver JAR? Or how to add JAR to the classpath in Ant?

Comment: jar is alreaday imported, it works good with eclipse compiler but it wont wort when i use ant coommand so probably  i don't know how to add JAR to the classpath in Ant

Comment: Invoking ANT is usually a `java` command, specifying arguments for the VM and for the program (ANT). Try adding `-cp path/postgresql_jdbc_driver.jar` after the `java` keyword... Often all this are in a script (a batch file with `.sh`, `.bat` or `.cmd` extension). Then you should add it in there...

Comment: i'm not able to set the classpath when i use java-cp path/postgresql_jdbc_driver.jar (instead of path i use the real path )